# Create Gallery with navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation drawer in my android project and I have few photos for which I want to create album in my project. Photo should be in project.

I have to create my own album and photos I want to keep inside the app.

Thanx for any help.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. The details are too vague.

Comment: for gallery you can use now view flipper.